# Status feedback problem

Tags: mobile, feedback, authentication

We have a mobile application. To register in our application you need to enter your phone number. After that, you receive an SMS with a code you need to enter to confirm your phone number.

There is a system which automatically takes the code from the received SMS and substitutes it to the field where the code should be inserted. But this system doesn't work in all countries, which is why there is a option to enter the received code manually.

When the system works and code is automatically substituted, users usually don't understand what just happened and why the "Enter PIN" screen suddenly disappeared.

So the problem is: how to show to user that code was automatically taken and everything is fine?

Solution 1:

Just show a popup with successful message afterwards.

Solution 2:

Insert code in the field automatically, but ask user to push "Verify" or "Enter" button manually.

Which one is more efficient or are there any other suggestions?

Comment: What if the user doesn't have SMS, or is charged for it and doesn't want to be dinged for the message price to get the code? Is there an alternate way of getting the code?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to inform by simple, short message on UI ("Code entered automatically"), probably near the inputs fields. Plus show user how Code is entering automatically (step by step, *, **, *** , ****). 
After that give user button which confirms Code and take him/her to another screen - it will provide more user control and time to understand what just happend.

iOS guideline says

> Subtle animation can give people meaningful feedback that helps clarify the results of their actions. For example, lists can animate the addition of a new row to help people track the change visually.

Comment: Variation of solution nr 2 will be less confusing than just skipping to a message.

Answer (score 0):

If you can detect that a country supports autofilling then don't display any input - just wait for confirmation SMS and accept it when it received. Another way - if you can detect detect when SMS received and it can't be accept automatically only then display input for it. It's usual for mobile user when need to enter something is displayed without any previous instructions.